# Extending a nested class method

Tags: c++, oop, inner-classes, nested-class

I have encountered a virtual method in a nested class.

```
##classone.h

class ClassOne: {
public:
  class InnerClass{
  public:
      virtual void method1();
      ...

##classone.cpp
void ClassOne::InnerClass::method1()
{
...
}
```

I am subclassing `ClassOne` and need to extend `method1()`. What need's to be done with the nested class in that situation?

**What I tried**

```
##subclassone.h

class SubClassOne: public ClassOne{
public:
    virtual void method1();

##subclassone.cpp

void SubClassOne::InnerClass::method1()
{
##New implementation
}
```

But that gives a `multiple definition of ClassOne::InnerClass::method1()`

Comment: You'll need to subclass `InnerClass` 1st of all, to override methods for it.

Comment: I think you should say `class SubClassOne: public ClassOne::InnerClass` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`method1` belongs to `ClassOne::InnerClass`, not `ClassOne`. When you inherit from `ClassOne`, the nested class from base class becomes a member of the derived class, too, and you can reach it by qualifying with either `ClassOne::` or `SubClassOne::`. Hence the double definition error regarding `method1`.

You'll need to sub-class `InnerClass`, too. If you still wish to derive from `ClassOne`, it would look like this:

```
class ClassOne {
public:
    class InnerClass {
    public:
        virtual void method1();
    };
};

void ClassOne::InnerClass::method1()
{
}

class SubClassOne : public ClassOne {
    class DerivedInnerClass : InnerClass { // 
        virtual void method1();
    };
};

void SubClassOne::DerivedInnerClass::method1()
{
}
```

Comment: I had this issue as well. The problem was that I forgot the public keyword when extended "ClassOne". 'class SubClassOne : public ClassOne {'