# Accessing base class methods from a subclassed nested class

Tags: c++, oop, inner-classes, nested-class

The question extends [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450244/extending-a-nested-class-method)

The situation is the following. I'm extending a virtual method of a inner class:

```
class ClassOne {
public:
    class InnerClass {
    public:
            virtual void method1();
    protected:
        friend class ClassOne
    };    
protected:
    oftenUsedMethod();
private:
    friend class InnerClass;
};

void ClassOne::InnerClass::method1()
{
    #Do stuff with oftenUsedMethod();
}

class SubClassOne : public ClassOne {
    class DerivedInnerClass : InnerClass { 
        virtual void method1();
    };
};

void SubClassOne::DerivedInnerClass::method1()
{
    ##I need the access to the oftenUsedMethod???
}
```

Here is an image to try to clarify the problem :)
[image]

`InnerClass` uses `ofthenUsedMethod()` in its methods, and has access to it. To be able to extend the methods, I need access to `ofthenUsedMethod()` in `DerivedInnerClass`. Can this be achieved?

Comment: I suspect your problem might be that you assume inner classes in C++ have an implicit pointer to an instance of the outer class like they do in Java.  This is not the case.  You'll need an object of `ClassOne` to call `oftenUsedMethod` on.

Comment: @5gon12eder `InnerClass` can call the `oftenUsedMethod` somehow. I have tried to scale the code down to the issue of the problem, could be I've missed some `friend` relations.

Comment: I don't know what “somehow” is without seeing your code but what you'll probably need to do is adding a `protected: ClassOne * outer;` member to `ClassOne::InnerClass` and then use `this->outer->oftenUsedMethod()`.  It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems to overcome:

1. Inner classes, by default, are not associated with an instance of the outer class, sou you'll have to make this dependency explicit by giving it a pointer to the outer class.  If you do this, you'll need to be careful that instances of the inner class don't outlive the object they are referring to.
2. The derived inner class is not derived from the outer class so it does not have access to its `protected` members.  What you can do is add a `protected` function into `InnerClass` that calls the function.  This function is a member of `InnerClass` and derived classes can call it.  Dynamic binding will do the rest.

Here is the above in C++:

```c++11
#include <iostream>

class ClassOne
{

protected:

  virtual void
  oftenUsedMethod()
  {
    std::clog << "ClassOne::oftenUsedMethod()" << std::endl;
  }

  class InnerClass
  {

  private:

    /** Pointer to an instance of the outer class. */
    ClassOne *const outer_;

  public:

    InnerClass(ClassOne *const outer) : outer_ {outer}
    {
    }

  protected:

    virtual void
    method1()
    {
      std::clog << "ClassOne::InnerClass::method1()" << std::endl;
      this->dispatch();
    }

    /**
     * Simply calls the protected member of the outer class.
     * Derived classes can therefore access it indirectly, too.
     *
     */
    void
    dispatch()
    {
      // Be aware: If *this->outer_ has already been destructed
      // (and there is no simple way for us to tell whether it has),
      // calling a member function on it will cause disaster.
      this->outer_->oftenUsedMethod();
    }
  };
};

class SubClassOne : public ClassOne
{

protected:

  virtual void
  oftenUsedMethod() override
  {
    std::clog << "SubClassOne::oftenUsedMethod()" << std::endl;
  }

  class DerivedInnerClass : public ClassOne::InnerClass
  {

    DerivedInnerClass(ClassOne *const outer) : InnerClass {outer}
    {
    }

  protected:

    virtual void
    method1() override
    {
      std::clog << "SubClassOne::DerivedInnerClass::method1()" << std::endl;
      this->dispatch();
    }
  };
};
```

The `override` is a C++11 feature, you don't need it but it makes your intention clear.

Comment: Did a recheck, there are `friend` relations between both base classes. Sorry about the mistake.

Comment: @Alan This could work too, but it is more intrusive and requires the base class be changed when adding a new derived class.  This is undesirable from a maintainer's point of view.

Comment: So in theory, if the base class (ClassOne) had a `friend class DerivedInnerClass` it would work? (I'm not going to do it, just checking the concepts :) )

Comment: @Alan If you manage to declare `SubClassOne::DerivedInnerClass` as a `friend` of `ClassOne`, then yes.  But I'm not sure how you would go about it.  You'd somehow need to forward-declare the nested class and this is not possible afaik.